# Issues with a migration from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2022

Tags: sql-server, ssas, database-migration, ssas-tabular

I have some problems with a migration from SQL Server 2016 to SQL Server 2022

In the SQL Server 2016 I have a DB in Analysis services and also have a job to update the data each 5 minutes and it works perfectly.

The issues comes when I tried to have the DB in SQL Server 2022 because I run out of space.

First I used Visual Studio Code with the SQL extension and the template "Import from server(tabular)" to recreate the model of the DB, after that I change the compatibility level to 1600, process all the tables of the DB and did a deploy to have the DB on the new server.

After that, I used SQL Server Agent to create a job with two steps that refresh the data of the new DB each 5 minutes (the first step process all the tables in "process Data" mode and the second step process the DB in "process Default" mode) .

But after enabled the job, in a few hours I run out of space in the disk (I have 80 GB of free space) but the SSMS says that the DB has an estimated size of 7GB.
What can I do to fix this? Is there anything I'm missing in the process to migrate that DB?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Perhaps you have set recovery mode FULL on your database? or your database files are large. Check the db settings in ssms